# Altium: Length match different parts of a line

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I design a PCB using Altium with some length sensitive lines. They have up to 4 connection points. Is there a way to length match the individual parts of the line?
Lengthmatching the complete line is easy, but I need the connections in the middle to be at the same distance as well.

Comment: By line you mean trace? Is this for a transmission line?

Comment: Yes line=trace ;-). I did it now by removing the trace exept the one part I need to equalize. Then I do this section by section. Not a nice way, but it works

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to split the net into multiple using [net ties](http://www.smtnet.com/library/files/upload/NetTies-and-How-to-Use-Them.pdf).
Then you can match the individual portions of the lines against each other as if they were any other net.